# Getting exception "Socket read operation has timed out" while using SSH.NET although the can connect to the sftp by using filezilla

Tags: sftp, ssh.net

I am trying to upload files using Renci.SshNet, but the connection times out each time, although i can connect successfully using SFTP client (filezilla).
I have used the below code and each time I get exception in the line (sftp.Connect). I get an exception "An exception of type 'Renci.SshNet.Common.SshOperationTimeoutException' occurred in Renci.SshNet.dll" 
{"Socket read operation has timed out"}

```
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo(host, port, username, password);
        using (var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
        {
            client.Connect();
            //Log.Info("Connected to SFTP", this);
            // byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv);
            FileStream streams = File.OpenRead(@"c:\sftp\Test.csv");
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[streams.Length];

            streams.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);

            using (var file = stream)
            {
                // sftp.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
                client.UploadFile(file, uploadFile + "/" + Path.GetFileName(path));
                // Log.Info("Upload to SFTP success", this);
            }
            streams.Close();
            client.Disconnect();
            // Log.Info("Disconnected from SFTP", this);
        }
```

Comment: Hi. Have you found the solution for this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution Piya ?

Comment: Anyone of you (@venkat14 or @khalidmehmoodawan) found any solution yet?